# Implication of peculiar data set

Tags: regression, modeling, dataset

I've got a dataset which has exactly the same values for the regressors for two of the eight geographical regions but different values for the response variable. What implication does it have on a statistical model which tries to treat these two regions as different?

Cheers!

Comment: It's not at all peculiar that you have a model with the same x's but different y's, any more than it would be weird to get a different result from counting the heads when tossing a coin ten times on two different occasions. That particular outcome is what the error term is for.

Comment: If you want meaningful answers you might want to provide more detail around the type of regressors (categorical, continuous?) and what you're measuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistical models relate regressors $X$ with response $Y$ by a function $f(X)$ as

$$Y=f(X)+\varepsilon$$

where $\varepsilon$ is a random variable usually called the error.

What you describe is actually one of the main reasons why statistical models exist. In your particular case, suppose the response for geographical regions $A$ and $B$ are equal, i.e. $X=X_A=X_B$; having, however, different responses $Y_A\neq Y_B$. Then the models are

$$Y_A=f(X)+\varepsilon_A$$
$$Y_B=f(X)+\varepsilon_B$$

with $\varepsilon_A\neq \varepsilon_B$, absolutely consistent with the model.

The implications are that there are (possibly infinitely many) variables that affect the response that are not being taken into consideration within the response $X$. If this variables were included in $X$, then $X_A\neq X_B$. These not-considered variables are represented in the model as random error $\varepsilon$.

Comment: However, does it imply such a model (just using the same explanatory variables obtained) will most likely be a bad model?

Comment: Given that your number of data points is low (n=8) and two of them are equally represented by $X$, collecting more information (increasing the number of variables) may be recommended.

Comment: Oh no, there are hundreds of observations per region, total observations in the thousands.